# My code .sh cant run. Help me

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, grep

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set port [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ps xu | grep "ssh -f -N -o ConnectTimeout=5 -D $port" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9
expect eol
```

[image]

I make sure 100% port 1234 is running. Because i check it ps aux|grep ssh . and see. So what wrong in my code ? Thank

Comment: So, um, why exactly are you using `expect`?

Comment: i dont know im newbie. Can you help me fix my code ?

Comment: When you run the script it will try to substitute argument #2 into $2. However, you only provided 1 argument. I'm not really proficient with shell commands but my guess is you should escape the $ in the script like so: awk '{ print \$2 }'

Comment: Try just having this in your .sh file:  spawn ps xu | grep "ssh -f -N -o ConnectTimeout=5 -D $1" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print \$2 }' | xargs kill -9

Comment: You could use `ssh <host> -O exit`, you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put this in a shell script, the $2 will be replaced by argument number 2:

```
                  v This
./myscript.sh one two
```

When you ran your script, you did not include a second argument.

However, this is besides the point, because you want, specifically:

```
awk '{ print $2 }'
```

You need to escape the '$' symbol with '\'.

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
spawn ps xu | grep "ssh -f -N -o ConnectTimeout=5 -D $1" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print \$2 }' | xargs kill -9
```

The first line wasn't necessary, since the port will be the first argument you can use '$1' to get it.

Answer (score 1):

this look like a complex way to issue a kill, if expect is not mandatory

```
#!/bin/bash
ps xu |awk -v port=$1 'index($0,"ssh -f -N -o ConnectTimeout=5 -D " port) > 0 { printf "kill %d\n",$2}' | bash
```

where

- `-v port=$1` initialive awk variable with $1
- `index($0,"...")` will search the current output of ps for ssh